# why my fileupload control is not working fine

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a FileUpload control in my asp.net page that it should upload my picture in some folder on the host .I put a condition that when it has file ,it starts uploading.
this the code .

```
 if (File2.HasFile)
 {
      string b = File2.FileName.ToString();
      File2.PostedFile.SaveAs(path + File2.FileName);
 }
```

but the condition never be true.I have two other FileUpload in that page .they are working fine .But this one is not working fine and the condition always is false.
what should I do?

this is the HTML code :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                   <ContentTemplate>
                       <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="style4" dir="rtl" 
                           style="border: thin solid #008080">
                           <tr>
                               <td>
                                   &nbsp;</td>
                               <td>
                                   &nbsp;</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                               <td>
                                   <div style=" border-width: thin; border-color: #008080; border-left-style: solid;">
                                       <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                                           AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" 
                                           ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" onrowcommand="GridView2_RowCommand" 
                                           PageSize="6" Width="130px" Height="200px" ShowHeader="False">
                                           <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                                           <Columns>
                                               <asp:TemplateField>
                                                   <ItemTemplate>
                                                       <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
                                                           CommandArgument='<%#Eval("PID") %>' CommandName="LnkEdit" 
                                                           Text='<%#Eval("Pname") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                                   </ItemTemplate>
                                               </asp:TemplateField>
                                           </Columns>
                                           <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
                                           <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                           <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                           <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                           <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
                                           <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                           <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
                                           <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
                                           <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
                                           <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
                                       </asp:GridView>
                                   </div>
                                   <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                               </td>
                               <td>
                                   <div style="float  :right">
                                       <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 500px">
                                           <tr>
                                               <td>
                                                   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="نام"></asp:Label>
                                               </td>
                                               <td align="right">
                                                   <asp:TextBox ID="TxTEditname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                               </td>
                                           </tr>
                                           <tr>
                                               <td>
                                                   <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text="زبان"></asp:Label>
                                               </td>
                                               <td align="right">
                                                   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server">
                                                       <asp:ListItem Value="en">English</asp:ListItem>
                                                       <asp:ListItem Value="fa">فارسی</asp:ListItem>
                                                   </asp:DropDownList>
                                               </td>
                                           </tr>
                                           <tr>
                                               <td>
                                                   <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="توضیحات"></asp:Label>
                                               </td>
                                               <td align="right">
                                                   <asp:TextBox ID="TxTEditdes" runat="server" Height="102px" 
                                                       TextMode="MultiLine" Width="380px"></asp:TextBox>
                                               </td>
                                           </tr>
                                           <tr>
                                               <td>
                                                   <asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" Text="عکس جدید"></asp:Label>
                                               </td>
                                               <td align="right">
                                                   <asp:FileUpload ID="File2" runat="server" />
                                               </td>
                                           </tr>
                                           <tr>
                                               <td>
                                                   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
                                                       Text="ثبت تغییرات" />
                                               </td>
                                               <td>
                                                   <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                               </td>
                                           </tr>
                                       </table>
                                   </div>
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                       </table>
                   </ContentTemplate>




               </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: We'll probably need to see more code to know for sure.  Can you reproduce this with minimal HTML and minimal server-side code and share a more complete codebase?  My first guess is that the file upload isn't part of the form for some reason.  Or, if you're using Web Forms, maybe you're resetting the control in `Page_Load`.

Comment: _Minimal_ HTML and _minimal_ server-side code... =)

Comment: You say there are two other `FileUpload` controls on the page, but they're not included in this code. Nor do you show the code-behind that uses them. You've also changed the code-behind pretty significantly since originally asking the question. Can you perhaps share the _actual_ code that causes the problem? And, again, minimal. A significant early step in debugging something like this is to reproduce it with as little surrounding cruft as possible.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx) Page:

> The following ASP.NET controls are not compatible with partial-page
>   updates, and are therefore not designed to work inside an UpdatePanel
>   control:
>
> - `FileUpload` and `HtmlInputFile` controls when they are used to upload files as    part of an asynchronous postback.
> - -
>
> To use a `FileUpload` or `HtmlInputFile` control inside an
>   *UpdatePanel* control, set the postback control that submits the file to be a `PostBackTrigger` control for the panel.

So you need to set Triggers property for postback control (Button etc)

Example:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
        </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code-behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
      {
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(MapPath("~/Files/" + FileUpload1.FileName));
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a difference

```
string b = FileUpload2.FileName.ToString();
File2.PostedFile.SaveAs(path + FileUpload2.FileName);
```

should it not be

```
string b = File2.FileName.ToString();
File2.PostedFile.SaveAs(path + File2.FileName);
```

Comment: And also stick to the namings guidelines/conventions

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake, You check File2 fileupload control and while saving the file you write FileUpload2.FileName .Use the Server.MapPath method to give the right path.

`File2.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/path")+File2.FileName`

This will be the right code

`File2.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/path")+File2.FileName`